# Configure Vim to insert text for Lines of Code

Tags: vim, count, lines

I'm using Vim for all program editing and I have a standard header I use at the top of all my source code files.  I have a .vimrc file set up to update certain fields in this header (like Last Modified) when I save any changes using :w

My question is, how do I put in a function to count lines of code, following the basic rule that only non-blank lines are counted?

I know within an open vim buffer, I can use

```
:%s/\n//gn
```

to count all lines, and

```
:%s/\n\n//gn
```

to count blank lines (basically count how many times two newlines appear in a row, indicating a blank line).  But how do I put this in my .vimrc file?

Here's the code fragment from my .vimrc that updates the header fields:

```
function! LastModified()
  if &modified
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let n = min([20, line("$")])
    keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's#^\(.\{,10}Last Modified:\).*#\1' .
          \ strftime(' %a %b %d, %Y  %I:%M%p') . '#e'
    keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's#^\(.\{,10}Filename:\).*#\1' .
          \ ' ' . @% . '#e'
    keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's#^\(.\{,10}LOC:\).*#\1' .
          \ ' ' . '' . '#e'
    call histdel('search', -1)
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
  endif
endfun
```

Also, I would just like to add, I know there are numerous other ways to do this (like using wc --lines from the shell) but I'm interested in learning how to really configure my editor (so call it a learning exercise).

Comment: You can also get the line count as `line("$")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually should not want to use `:s` here:

```
function! CountNonEmpty()
    return len(filter(getline(1, line('$')), '!empty(v:val)'))
endfunction
```

---

By the way, I would have used getline+map+setline to implement your header updater:

```
function! LastModified()
    if &modified
        " If number of buffer lines is < 20, then getline(1, 20)"
        " will return only existing lines without any errors "
        call setline(1, map(getline(1, 20), 'substitute(substitute(substitute(v:val, '.
        \'"^\\v(.{,10}Last Modified:).*", "\\1 ".strftime("%s %b %d, %Y  %I:%M%p"), ""),'.
        \'"^\\v(.{,10}Filename:).*",      "\\1 ".escape(@%, "&\\~"), ""),'.
        \'"^\\v(.{,10}LOC:).*",           "\\1 ", "")'))
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want, works well.  Is there a way I could not count lines that had 3 characters or less?

Comment: @dvanaria: you can replace `!empty(v:val)` with any expression that returns number. For your request it is `v:val=~#"^.\\{,3}$"`.

Comment: Would I just substitute the expression in !empty(v:val) with the second example? for example: return len(filter(getline(1, line('$')), '!empty(v:val=~#"^.\\{,2}$")'))

Comment: @dvanaria You should replace the whole second argument to `filter()`, not `empty()` argument. `empty()` is a function that checks whether its argument is empty and for strings it is equivalent to `v:val==#""` or `v:val=~#"^$"`, `=~#` is an operator that checks whether its left argument matches regular expression that is its right argument. `!empty(v:val=~#"^.\\{,2}$")` will work because `empty(number)` is equivalent to `number==0`, `=~#` will return 0 when left str doesn't match right regex and 1 otherwise, so `!empty(v:val=~#"^.\\{,2}$")` and `v:val=~#"^.\\{,2}$"` will yield the same results.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
function! CountNonEmpty()
  redir => g:nonblank
  silent %s/^.\+$/&/n
  redir END
  return substitute(g:nonblank, '\n\s*\(\d\+\)\D.*$', '\1', '')
endfunction
```

- :redir =>  Stores the output of the following ex commands into the given variable. See `:help :redir`